# Keras/Tensorflow INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I am training a UNET for CT image segmentation, but I keep getting an illegal argument error at 2498 steps into the training. For background, I am using Keras and used https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet as a guide. The error, which is "INVALID_ARGUMENT:  required broadcastable shapes," is detected when the loss is computed during the 2498th step. I have tried shuffling and not shuffling the data and changing the number of classes, but I have no idea what is causing the error. I have tried changing the number of classes and that didn't help. I also changed the steps per epoch to various different values, and that didn't help either. The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 47, in <module>
    model.fit(myGene,validation_data=validationGene, validation_steps=550,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=100,callbacks=[model_checkpoint, tbcallback],  use_multiprocessing=False)
  File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'TverskyLoss/mul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "__main__.py", line 47, in <module>
      model.fit(myGene,validation_data=validationGene, validation_steps=550,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=100,callbacks=[model_checkpoint, tbcallback],  use_multiprocessing=False)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 918, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/home/jrocca/model.py", line 32, in TverskyLoss
      TP = ks.backend.sum((inputs * targets))
Node: 'TverskyLoss/mul'
Detected at node 'TverskyLoss/mul' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "__main__.py", line 47, in <module>
      model.fit(myGene,validation_data=validationGene, validation_steps=550,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=100,callbacks=[model_checkpoint, tbcallback],  use_multiprocessing=False)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 918, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/home/jrocca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/home/jrocca/model.py", line 32, in TverskyLoss
      TP = ks.backend.sum((inputs * targets))
Node: 'TverskyLoss/mul'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node TverskyLoss/mul}}]]
     [[assert_greater_equal_2/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_43/_103]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node TverskyLoss/mul}}]]


data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.2,
                    width_shift_range=0.05, # this is in percentages / out of 1
                    height_shift_range=0.05, # this is in percentages / out of 1
                    shear_range=0.05,
                    zoom_range=0.05,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    fill_mode='nearest')
```

Here is the **main**.py file:

```
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.2,
                    width_shift_range=0.05, 
                    height_shift_range=0.05, 
                    shear_range=0.05,
                    zoom_range=0.05,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    fill_mode='nearest')
    
val_data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0,
                         width_shift_range=0,
                         height_shift_range=0,
                         shear_range=0,
                         zoom_range=0,
                         horizontal_flip=False)

myGene = trainGenerator(3, 'DataHeartNoUpsampling/training','image','label',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)

validationGene = trainGenerator(3, 'DataHeartNoUpsampling/validation','image','label', aug_dict=val_data_gen_args)

model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('unet_heart.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
tbcallback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="logsTensorboard2", histogram_freq=1, embeddings_freq=1)

model.fit(myGene,validation_data=validationGene, validation_steps=550,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=100,callbacks=[model_checkpoint, tbcallback],  use_multiprocessing=False)
model.save("./July12")
```

The model file is:

```
ALPHA = 0.25
BETA = 0.75

def TverskyLoss(targets, inputs, alpha=ALPHA, beta=BETA, smooth=1e-6):
  # flatten label and prediction tensors
  inputs = ks.backend.flatten(inputs)
  targets = ks.backend.flatten(targets)

  print("***     The shape of the inputs is "+tf.shape(inputs) + "     ***")
  print("***     The shape of the targets is "+tf.shape(targets)+ "     ***")

  # True Positives, False Positives & False Negatives
  TP = ks.backend.sum((inputs * targets))
  FP = ks.backend.sum(((1 - targets) * inputs))
  FN = ks.backend.sum((targets * (1 - inputs)))

  Tversky = (TP + smooth) / (TP + alpha * FP + beta * FN + smooth)

  return 1 - Tversky


def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (512,512,1)):
    inputs = ks.Input(input_size)
    conv1 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv1")(inputs)
    conv1 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = ks.layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = ks.layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = ks.layers.concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = ks.layers.concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = ks.layers.concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(ks.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = ks.layers.concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = ks.layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = ks.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)

    precision = ks.metrics.Precision()
    AUC = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
    recall=tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
    MSE = tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(name="mean_squared_error", dtype=None)
    RMSE = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(
    name="root_mean_squared_error", dtype=None)
    BCE = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(
    name="binary_crossentropy", dtype=None, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0)
    model.compile(optimizer=ks.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5), loss=TverskyLoss, metrics=[AUC, recall, MSE, RMSE, BCE, precision, 'accuracy'])


    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix tensorflow==2.5.0. The output order of the model is changed after tensorflow==2.6.0, which caused the error.

I think so, I am not sure. please check your version